# Do not want the Images to load and CSS to render on Firefox in Selenium WebDriver - Python

Tags: python, css, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium 2 with python bindings to fetch some data from our partner's site. But on an average it's taking me around 13 secs to perform this operation.

I was looking for a way to disable the images css and flash etc.

I am using Firefox 3.6 and also using pyvirtualdisplay to to prevent opening of firefox window. Any other optimization to speed up firefox will be also helpful.
I have already tried `network.http.*` options but does not help much.

And also set the `permissions.default.image = 2`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I have figured out a way to prevent Firefox from loading CSS, images and Flash.

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

def disableImages(self):
    ## get the Firefox profile object
    firefoxProfile = FirefoxProfile()
    ## Disable CSS
    firefoxProfile.set_preference('permissions.default.stylesheet', 2)
    ## Disable images
    firefoxProfile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
    ## Disable Flash
    firefoxProfile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so',
                                  'false')
    ## Set the modified profile while creating the browser object 
    self.browserHandle = webdriver.Firefox(firefoxProfile)
```

Thanks again @Simon and @ernie for your suggestions.

Comment: Solution for disabling images no longer works with latest version of firefox - see my answer below (thanks to Alecxe who pointed in right direction)

Comment: @kyrenia Is it still not working?  If it does not, I will accept the answer that actually works now.

Comment: Yes - I believe that, at least for images, changing the 'set preferences' flag is blocked in all of the recent releases of firefox (I think you can still disable css and flash that way)

Comment: css is not disabled when I use this!

Answer (score 13):

## New Edit

It has been so long since I've written this and I can say the field of web automation (either for testing or crawling/scraping purposes) has changed a lot. The major browsers have already presented a `--headless` flag and even interactive shell. No more change the good old `DISPLAY` variable on Linux.

Firefox has also changed, migrating to [Servo](https://servo.org) engine written with Rust. I've tried the profile below with a contemporary version (specifically, 62.0). Some worked, some did not. Keep that in mind.

---

I'm just extending [the answer of kyrenia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31576782/2926992) in this question. However, disabling the CSS might cause Jquery not to be able to manipulate DOM elements. Use QuickJava and those below:

```
profile.set_preference("network.http.pipelining", True)
profile.set_preference("network.http.proxy.pipelining", True)
profile.set_preference("network.http.pipelining.maxrequests", 8)
profile.set_preference("content.notify.interval", 500000)
profile.set_preference("content.notify.ontimer", True)
profile.set_preference("content.switch.threshold", 250000)
profile.set_preference("browser.cache.memory.capacity", 65536) # Increase the cache capacity.
profile.set_preference("browser.startup.homepage", "about:blank")
profile.set_preference("reader.parse-on-load.enabled", False) # Disable reader, we won't need that.
profile.set_preference("browser.pocket.enabled", False) # Duck pocket too!
profile.set_preference("loop.enabled", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.chrome.toolbar_style", 1) # Text on Toolbar instead of icons
profile.set_preference("browser.display.show_image_placeholders", False) # Don't show thumbnails on not loaded images.
profile.set_preference("browser.display.use_document_colors", False) # Don't show document colors.
profile.set_preference("browser.display.use_document_fonts", 0) # Don't load document fonts.
profile.set_preference("browser.display.use_system_colors", True) # Use system colors.
profile.set_preference("browser.formfill.enable", False) # Autofill on forms disabled.
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.deleteTempFileOnExit", True) # Delete temprorary files.
profile.set_preference("browser.shell.checkDefaultBrowser", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.startup.homepage", "about:blank")
profile.set_preference("browser.startup.page", 0) # blank
profile.set_preference("browser.tabs.forceHide", True) # Disable tabs, We won't need that.
profile.set_preference("browser.urlbar.autoFill", False) # Disable autofill on URL bar.
profile.set_preference("browser.urlbar.autocomplete.enabled", False) # Disable autocomplete on URL bar.
profile.set_preference("browser.urlbar.showPopup", False) # Disable list of URLs when typing on URL bar.
profile.set_preference("browser.urlbar.showSearch", False) # Disable search bar.
profile.set_preference("extensions.checkCompatibility", False) # Addon update disabled
profile.set_preference("extensions.checkUpdateSecurity", False)
profile.set_preference("extensions.update.autoUpdateEnabled", False)
profile.set_preference("extensions.update.enabled", False)
profile.set_preference("general.startup.browser", False)
profile.set_preference("plugin.default_plugin_disabled", False)
profile.set_preference("permissions.default.image", 2) # Image load disabled again
```

What does it do? You can actually see what it does in comment lines. However, I've also found a couple of about:config entries to increase the performance. For example, the code above does not load the font or colors of the document, but it loads CSS, so Jquery -or any other library- can manipulate DOM elements and does not raise an error. (For a further debug, you still download CSS, but your browser will jump the lines which contains a special font-family or color definition. So browser will download and load CSS, but use system-defaults in styling and renders the page faster.)

For more information, [check out this article](https://erayerdin.com/how-to-make-selenium-load-faster-with-firefox-in-python-ck7ncjyvw00sd8ss1v4i5xob1).

---

## Edit (Tests)

I just made a performance test. You do not really need to take the results serious since I made this test just once, for you to have an idea.

I made the test in an old machine on 2.2 gHZ Intel Pentium processor, 3 gB RAM with 4gB swap area, Ubuntu 14.04 x64 system.

The test takes three steps:

- **Driver Loading Performance**: The seconds wasted to load the driver in `webdriver` module.
- **Page Loading Performance**: The seconds wasted to load the page. It also includes the internet speed, however the render process is included as well.
- **DOM Inspecting Performance**: DOM inspecting speed on the page.

I used [this page](http://www.anitsayac.com/?year=2015) as subject and inspected `.xxy a` as CSS selector. Then I used a special process one by one.

#### Selenium, Firefox, No Profile

```
Driver Loading Performance: 13.124099016189575
Page Loading Performance: 3.2673521041870117
DOM Inspecting Performance: 67.82778096199036
```

#### Selenium, Firefox, Profile Above

```
Driver Loading Performance: 7.535895824432373
Page Loading Performance: 2.9704301357269287
DOM Inspecting Performance: 64.25136017799377
```

## Edit (About Headlessness)

I made a test maybe a month ago, but I could not take the results. However, I want to mention that driver loading, page loading and DOM inspecting speed decreases under *ten seconds* when Firefox is used headless. That was really cool.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately the option `firefox_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)` no longer seems to work to disable images with the latest version of Firefox - [for reason see Alecxe's answer to my question [Can't turn off images in Selenium / Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571726/cant-turn-off-images-in-selenium-firefox) ]

The best solution i had was to use the firefox extension quickjava , which amongst other things can disable images- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/quickjava/

My Python code:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

 firefox_profile.add_extension(folder_xpi_file_saved_in + "\\quickjava-2.0.6-fx.xpi")
 firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.curVersion", "2.0.6.1") ## Prevents loading the 'thank you for installing screen'
 firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Images", 2)  ## Turns images off
 firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.AnimatedImage", 2)  ## Turns animated images off

 driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile)
 driver.get(web_address_desired)
```

Disabling CSS (and i think flash) still work with firefox propertiees. but they and other parts can also be switched off by adding the lines:

```
  firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.CSS", 2)  ## CSS
  firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Cookies", 2)  ## Cookies
  firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Flash", 2)  ## Flash
  firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Java", 2)  ## Java
  firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.JavaScript", 2)  ## JavaScript
  firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Silverlight", 2)
```

Comment: Setting `permissions.default.image` works for me on Firefox 66.0.5.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable images/css using the Web Developer toolbar Addon.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/

go to CSS->Disable and Images->Disable

Comment: Thanks Simon I will give it a try , but can i do it through firefox profile. I will be using selenium grid 2 to create a cluster of machines that will get this data for me. I would like to have this done through configuration or code changes (i.e in the selenium code I am writing).Please also let me know if this is doable.

Comment: I assume a Greasemonkey script to remove css/images the same?

Comment: You can use the addon and create a custom profile, and then use the information in the "Modifying the Firefox Profile" section of http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html to load the profile.

Added as a comment since I haven't tested the custom profile bit . . .

Comment: thanks ernie and Simon I will give both the approaches a try and will post the group about the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone interested in still using the original straight-forward approach suggested by Anupam:

Just install firefox version 20.0.1 (https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/20.0.1/) - works perfectly fine.

Other versions may work as well (versions 32 and higher and versions 3.6.9 and lower do NOT work)

Answer (score 0):

Tossing in my 2¢.

Better to use javascript snippets to accomplish.

```python
driver.execute_script(
   'document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(function(ev){ev.remove()});'
);
```

That will remove the img elements. If you do this right after you load the page, they will have little chance to download image data.

Here is a similar solution I found elsewhere on StackOverflow. (Can't find it anymore)

```python
driver.execute_script(
   "document.head.parentNode.removeChild(document.head)"
);
```