# How to prevent css and img download in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Is it possible to prevent img and css download in phantomjs webdriver(selenium)?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157994/do-not-want-images-to-load-and-css-to-render-on-firefox

Comment: phantomjs driver uses webkit.

Comment: Search for "phantomjs adblock" in Google.

Comment: You can make selenium go through a proxy, that proxy can be as simple as a small python script that you can determine whether to fetch/return a resource or block it with you custom heuristics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check [phantomjs  API](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html), an option can be passed as:
--load-images=[true|false] load all inlined images (default is true). Also accepted: [yes|no].

However, you cannot block CSS download AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `HtmlUnitDriver` on `Java`, you can use following method to modify the webclient options:

```
 @Override
    protected WebClient modifyWebClient(WebClient client) {
        client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        return client;
    }
```

hope this helps