# Disable images in Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Because Webdriver waits for the entire page to load before going on to the next line, I think disabling images, css and javascript will speed things up.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

def disableImages(self):
    ## get the Firefox profile object
    firefoxProfile = FirefoxProfile()
    ## Disable CSS
    firefoxProfile.set_preference('permissions.default.stylesheet', 2)
    ## Disable images
    firefoxProfile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
    ## Disable Flash
    firefoxProfile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so',
                                      'false')
    ## Set the modified profile while creating the browser object 
    self.browserHandle = webdriver.Firefox(firefoxProfile)
```

I got the code from stackoverflow [Do not want images to load and CSS to render on Firefox in Selenium WebDriver tests with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157994/do-not-want-images-to-load-and-css-to-render-on-firefox-in-selenium-webdriver-te)

But when I add

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.stackoverflow.com/")
```

to the end, it still loads images :/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*UPDATE*: The answer might not work any longer since [`permissions.default.image` became a frozen setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31572457/771848) and cannot be changed. Please try with `quickjava` extension (link to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31576684/771848)).

---

You need to pass `firefox_profile` instance to the `webdriver` constructor:

```
from selenium import webdriver

firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefox_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.stylesheet', 2)
firefox_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
firefox_profile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so', 'false')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
driver.get('http://www.stackoverflow.com/')

driver.close()
```

And this is how it would be displayed:

[image]

Comment: This answer unfortunately will no longer work, because firefox won't allow changes to the `default.image` value any more - thanks to alecxe who pointed me in the right direction - my code to solve is below.

Comment: @kyrenia really? I have Firefox 41 and still does work.

Comment: @erm3nda - was certainly a problem I was experiencing around July [2015], which would have probably been Firefox 39 - if no longer applies, then disabling via `firefox_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)` is obviously a cleaner solution.

Comment: Because it's obvious, i commented it... some lazy reader can think that using a extension it's better without even try it ;P

Answer (score 20):

Unfortunately the option `firefox_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)` will no longer work to disable images with the latest version of Firefox - [for reason see Alecxe's answer to my question [Can't turn off images in Selenium / Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571726/cant-turn-off-images-in-selenium-firefox) ]

The best solution i had was to use the firefox extension quickjava , which amongst other things can disable images- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/quickjava/

My Python code:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

 firefox_profile.add_extension(folder_xpi_file_saved_in + "\\quickjava-2.0.6-fx.xpi")
 firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.curVersion", "2.0.6.1") ## Prevents loading the 'thank you for installing screen'
 firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Images", 2)  ## Turns images off
 firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.AnimatedImage", 2)  ## Turns animated images off

 driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile)
 driver.get(web_address_desired)
```

Other things can also be switched off by adding the lines:

```
  firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.CSS", 2)  ## CSS
  firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Cookies", 2)  ## Cookies
  firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Flash", 2)  ## Flash
  firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Java", 2)  ## Java
  firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.JavaScript", 2)  ## JavaScript
  firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Silverlight", 2)  ## Silverlight
```

Comment: Interesting Java extension :D never see it.

Comment: This should be best answer! Thanks, this helped me a lot.

Comment: I had to use `2.0.6` version. Last version (`2.0.7`) raises an `AddonFormatError` exception. It seems having something to do with the manifest file but both are the same.

Comment: Setting `permissions.default.image` works for me on Firefox 66.0.5.

Comment: I added Image Block X, which works great :) https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/image-block-x/

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me either. From the "reason" links referred by kyrenia I gathered that Firefox overrides the "permissions.default.image" preference on the first startup and I was able to prevent that by doing:

```
# Arbitrarily high number
profile.set_preference('browser.migration.version', 9001)
```

Which seems to be ok since I create the profile on each driver startup so there is nothing to actually be migrated.

Answer (score 2):

I understand this is a [python](/questions/tagged/python) question, but it helped me with [facebook/php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver). (First result in search engine for `php webdriver disable javascript`)

I thought I'd post my code (altered version of @kyrenia answer for [php](/questions/tagged/php)) to help others get up and running.

---

## Install Everything

1. Download and install [facebook/php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver). `composer require facebook/webdriver`
2. [Download Selenium](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) & Start it. `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-#.jar`
3. [Download Quick Java](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/quickjava/) and place it into your project directory.

---

## Usage

```php
use Facebook\WebDriver\Firefox\FirefoxProfile;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Firefox\FirefoxDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;

// Change this to the path of you xpi
$extensionPath = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/../bin/selenium/quickjava-2.0.6-fx.xpi';

// Build our firefox profile
$profile = new FirefoxProfile();
$profile->addExtension($extensionPath);
$profile->setPreference('thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.curVersion', '2.0.6.1');
$profile->setPreference('thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Images', 2);
$profile->setPreference('thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.AnimatedImage', 2);
$profile->setPreference('thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.CSS', 2);
//$profile->setPreference('thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Cookies', 2);
$profile->setPreference('thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Flash', 2);
$profile->setPreference('thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Java', 2);
//$profile->setPreference('thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.JavaScript', 2);
$profile->setPreference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Silverlight", 2);

// Create DC
$dc = DesiredCapabilities::firefox();
$dc->setCapability(FirefoxDriver::PROFILE, $profile);

// Create our new driver
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $dc);
$driver->get('http://stackoverflow.com');

// The HTML Source code
$html = $driver->getPageSource();

// Firefox should be open and you can see no images or css was loaded
```

View more preference settings here:
https://github.com/ThatOneGuyDotNet/QuickJava/blob/master/defaults/preferences/defaults.js