# Selenium: How to disable image loading with firefox and python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I have read similar questions and one was supposed to be the answer, but when I tried it, it only gave a partial solution.
I refer to this question: [Disable images in Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214473/disable-images-in-selenium-python)

My problem is that I tried the solution and some of the images do not appear, but images that arrive from:

```html
<img href="www.xxx.png">
```

Are being loaded.
Is there a way to tell firefox/selenium not to get it?
If not, is there a way to discard it from the dom element that I get back, via:

```
self._browser.get(url)
content=self._browser.page_source
```

for example by doing some kind of find replace on the dom tree?
The browser configuration is the same browser from the previous question:

```
firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
# Disable CSS
firefox_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.stylesheet', 2)
# Disable images
firefox_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
# Disable Flash
firefox_profile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so', 'false')
# Set the modified profile while creating the browser object
self._browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
```

**Update**:

I kept on digging and what I learned is that if I inspect the text document that the selenium/firefox combo did I see that, it didn't bring the images and kept them as links.
But when I did:

```
self._browser.save_screenshot("info.png")
```

I got a 24 mega file with all the img links loaded.
Can anyone explain to me this matter?
Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

You can disable images using the following code:

```
firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefox_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
firefox_profile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so', 'false')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
```

if you need to block some specific url... hm...
I think you need to add string:

```
127.0.0.1 www.someSpecificUrl.com
```

to the hosts file before test start and delete it after test finish.

Comment: Does it work? I think, it needs False instead of string "false". It should be boolean. Pls advice.

Comment: Works for me. https://www.dropbox.com/s/o9wlmycti3yjg99/Screenshot%202018-01-26%2021.25.34.png?dl=0

Comment: @mrtipale, yes, it needs to be boolean.

Comment: It depends to language that you are use. In some languages it is bool, in some - string.

Answer (score 5):

In the latest Firefox versions `permissions.default.image` **can't be changed**. To disable the images, either switch to ChromeDriver or use alternative extentions as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31572457/9134517).