# Can't turn off images in Selenium / Firefox

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am looking to disable images in Firefox when using Selenium. It should be a simple update of the preferences in firefox, which is documented on the instructions on [Disable images in Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214473/disable-images-in-selenium-python)

However when i run, images display, and when i enter about:config, the value for `permissions.default.image` is still 1, rather than 2 which i have tried setting it to.

My code (written in Python) is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefox_profile.set_preference("permissions.default.image", 2)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile)
driver.get(web_address)
```

For reference, this code works perfect with another change to preference e.g. turning off csv files with the line `firefox_profile.set_preference("permissions.default.stylesheet",2)`. The only difference i can tell between the csv setting and the image one, is that the line `permissions.default.image` already exists in about:config (i.e. without me setting it), however the line `permissions.default.stylesheet` does not. ... it seems that i can add new lines in with the value i want, but not change an existing one (or it is beein over-ridden by Selenium after i enter my value).

Comment: did you also disable flash? firefox_profile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so', 'false')

Comment: Which selenium and which Firefox versions are you using? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe Firefox 39, and Salenium 2.46.0.  Also, it seems that i can't change default values - i can create the value "permissions.default.image_new" with value 2, but not change "permissions.default.image" from 1 to 2

Comment: @kyrenia yup, I'm able to reproduce the issue, working on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I understand, this problem is related to the following Firefox issues:

- [Remove "Load images automatically" checkbox from Prefs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=851701)
- [Get rid of options that kill our product](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=851698)

That means that [`permissions.default.image`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Permissions.default.image) is frozen, cannot be changed and does nothing.

---

Alternatives:

- use [Image Block](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/image-block/) extension
- switch to `Chrome` ([Disable images in Selenium ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433109/disable-images-in-selenium-chromedriver))

Comment: Thanks Alecxe! Followed your advice on using extensions although found QuickJava worked best, as Image Block did not support latest version of firefox. I have shared my code which solves problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214473/disable-images-in-selenium-python

Comment: Setting `permissions.default.image` works for me on Firefox 66.0.5.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. the solution is bellow in 3 steps.
1- creating new profile for Firefox. in Windows completely close Firefox. press (Window+R) , write `firefox.exe -p` then press enter and create a new profile.
2-open Firefox with the created profile then open about:config in navigation bar and find `permissions.default.image` and make it's number 2.
3-change your code like bellow

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("your_profile_name");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a code sample for disabling images.

```
#DISABLE IMAGES ON FIREFOX
def disable_images(driver):
    driver.get("about:config")
    driver.find_element("id","warningButton").click()
    searchArea=driver.find_element("id","about-config-search")
    searchArea.send_keys("permissions.default.image")
    editButton=driver.find_element("xpath","/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]/button")
    editButton.click()
    editArea=driver.find_element("xpath","/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[1]/form/input")
    editArea.send_keys("2")
    saveButton=driver.find_element("xpath","/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]/button")
    saveButton.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023-10, it **does** work again, though the code has changed a bit since selenium 4:

```py
import shutil

from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxProfile, Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("permissions.default.image", 2)

options = Options()
options.profile = profile

service = Service(executable_path=shutil.which("geckodriver"))
driver = Firefox(service=service, options=options)
```