# Firefox doesn't respect my desired_capability to not load images

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium-webdriver, configuration, capybara

I used `profile["permissions.default.image"] = 2` earlier but now it doesn't work for me:

```
require "capybara/rspec"
require "selenium/webdriver"

Capybara.register_driver :my_driver do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  profile["permissions.default.image"] = 2
  desired_capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox firefor_profile: profile
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
    desired_capabilities: desired_capabilities,
    browser: :firefox,
  )
end
Capybara.default_driver = :my_driver


feature do
  scenario do
    visit "http://lenta.ru"
    STDIN.gets
  end
end
```

I still see images.

```
$ /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -v
Mozilla Firefox 38.3.0

gem "selenium-webdriver", "2.48.0"
```

Comment: It seems that it's no longer possible to define this preference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571726/cant-turn-off-images-in-selenium-firefox/31572457#31572457

Comment: @FlorentB. damn, I hoped it's smth fundamentally wrong in my code so it could explain why I can't make another option to work (supressing Download dialog), that I can't ask properly on SO because it's impossible to reproduce without accessing specific website my company is working on.

Comment: _Impossible to reproduce_ means it uses 'ng-grid' Angular plugin to create and download file dynamically (not through the network), that is not so trivial thing to debug or find detailed success story about that.

Comment: Resolved that issue about downloading -- content-type from grid-ui plugin was application/octet-stream and Capybara::Selenium::Driver constructor had to get :profile instead of :desired_capabilities.

Comment: @FlorentB. since noone else came here to answer, you may make an answer from your comment so I could accept it.