# Using web driver to get all text from a source page in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver (firefox) to crawl some data from a website. I just found that opening the web page is slower than just opening the source of that web page. In other words, it took much longer to go to `'www.google.com'` than to go to `'view-source:www.google.com'`

So I was wondering whether I can use webdriver to get all text from a source page, rather than a normal page.

I tried using driver.page_source for the source page but it returned some mess that I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the source use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). Install it with pip:

```
pip install requests
```

And use it like so:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://google.com/")
# r.content, r.text, r.json(), r.status can be used
```

For advanced usage refer to the documentation above.

Note: If you need to parse the html use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and pass it `r.content`.

Comment: Yes, but I have to use web driver because I need to manually pass the rechaptcha check.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861775/python-selenium-accessing-html-source) should provide you with options to get the source code. Also, to optimize load speeds you could disable images like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214473/disable-images-in-selenium-python).

Comment: @user3182260 In order to pass the captcha check, you'll probably need to render the page, not just download the source. You might try PhantomJS instead of Selenium + browser. Or, it might render faster in another browser.