# How to disable images in Selenium Webdriver Chromedriver

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The following code does not prevent images from being loaded into selenium chromedriver:

```
const {
    Builder, By, Key, until
} = require('selenium-webdriver');
require('chromedriver');

(async function example() {
    const chromeDesktop = {
        prefs: {
            profile: {
                default_content_setting_values: {
                    images: 2
                }
            }
        }
    };
    let driver = await new Builder().withCapabilities(chromeDesktop).forBrowser('chrome').build();
    try {
        await driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=batman');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } finally {
        await driver.quit();
    }
})();
```

package.json:

```
"chromedriver": "^2.38.0",
"selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1",
```

I am using Chrome Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit). I used the code from this post: [JavaScript: Disable images in Selenium ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40035343/javascript-disable-images-in-selenium-chromedriver?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and tried changing **managed_default_content_settings** to **default_content_setting_values** as per a user comment but had no luck with either.

Comment: Are you running this code in an headless environment? Some of the profile settings are not honored in headless mode.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by headless. I call the script I posted like "node script.js"

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this versions and works for me

"selenium-webdriver": "^4.1.0"

chrome version 97.0.4692.71

```
const {Builder} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const chromeOptios=new chrome.Options();
chromeOptios.setUserPreferences({
profile:{
default_content_settings:{
images: 2
},
managed_default_content_settings:{
images: 2
}
}}
  )

const driver=await browser.setChromeOptions(chromeOptios).build();
```