# Disable css rendering in chrome driver using selenium, java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to disable CSS in Selenium with Chrome driver. My code looks like this

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Path to chrome driver");

Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.managed_default_content_settings.images", 2);

options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.sampleurl.com/);
```

I googled it. But I can't get the perfect solution to disable CSS.

Comment: why do you want to disable it?

Comment: Only I need javascript rendered DOM of the website. I don't want image and CSS loaded DOM because it may affect my rendering time.https://stackoverflow.com/users/7305183/murthi

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this response can help you : [Do not want images to load and CSS to render on Firefox in Selenium WebDriver tests with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157994/do-not-want-images-to-load-and-css-to-render-on-firefox-in-selenium-webdriver-te)

```
firefoxProfile.addPreference("permissions.default.stylesheet", 2)
firefoxProfile.addPreference("permissions.default.image", 2)
```

If you set it up on the profile, it must work.