# How to load only html from web pages in selenium

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to load only html from web pages in selenium?

I need only html of requested page  without css and javascript.

Comment: Could I ask why?  Are the CSS and JavaScript files so large that loading them is significantly slowing down the selenium tests?

Comment: I want to use `selenium` for web scrapping

Comment: as @BrianHoover suggests, OP, you will very likely need JS to scrape a lot of sites properly -- since elements are loaded or altered using JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need selenium for web-scraping, strictly speaking, you would still need need javascript and css files since they can take a significant part in the page load and rendering. For example, several parts of a page can be loaded with additional ajax calls, or inserted via a custom javascript logic.

Also, if you want only HTML part of a page, why do you need to involve a real browser?

If you still want to prevent js and css files from loading, you can configure certain permissions in Firefox through tweaking `FirefoxProfile` preferences, see:

- [Do not want images to load and CSS to render on Firefox in Selenium WebDriver tests with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157994/do-not-want-images-to-load-and-css-to-render-on-firefox-in-selenium-webdriver-te)
- [FirefoxDriver: how to disable javascript,css and make sendKeys type instantly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3526361/771848)