# Selenium WebDriver Load both a Capability and Profile

Tags: java, selenium

Looking to load both DesiredCapabilities and a FirefoxProfile, can't figure it out and can't find an answer for it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load only html from web pages in selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766994/how-to-load-only-html-from-web-pages-in-selenium)

Answer (score 2):

There is the `FirefoxDriver.PROFILE` capability for RemoteWebDriver.
For example,

```
FirefoxProfile yourProfile = new FirefoxProfile("path_to_your_profile");    
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, yourProfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your firefox profile, i.e: "profileFF"

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("profileFF");
cap.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, myprofile );
```

OR

```
 DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();  
 File firefoxProfileFolder = new File("/path/to/your/firefox/profile/profileFF");
 FirefoxProfile myprofile = new FirefoxProfile(firefoxProfileFolder);
 cap.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, myprofile );
```